# design of Java classes and packages

Tags: java, class, oop, design-patterns, package

I have a context class -> prototype.context -> which apps can create objects of, but cannot extend. The system developer can however extend the classes to more types. The package of system classes would be prototype.system and prototype.dbengine . These classes should have full access to context objects, but other classes should not.

If I keep the fields in context class as package access, these classes cannot access it, because they are from a different package. So how should I name the packages so that the classes are available to other developers, and also have full access to system classes?

Comment: Access has nothing to do with names.

Comment: package access works based on package names, right?

Comment: more info on similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18494938/difference-between-protected-and-package-private-access-modifiers-in-java

Comment: A) Prefer composition over inheritence.  You should probably have all your classes stand alone and delegate to another class rather than inheriting in any but the most trivial cases. They should all implement the same interface though.  You would use this interface in methods that previously took the parent/base class as a parameter.  B) Why prevent your users from extending your classes?  This is the kind of decision that makes people think OO is bad--because someone arbitrarily (and usually deliberately) limited their flexibility.

Comment: the inheritance is a very important part of the design because it allows creating more forms of the base class type. I cannot restrict or prevent or prefer not to have inheritance as it is not what I'm trying to design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is actually a simulation of the C++ friend-class feature. A nice trick is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18634125/2886891

Comment: that design pattern restricts using the classes in other ways, it does not work the way I want it to work. And also, having mutual working classes is not the requirement here.

Comment: although initially skeptical, I've managed to get the solution using the friend function. Thank you :)

Comment: It was my pleasure :) To help you as well as to learn this nice trick in Java :)

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely have to use package-private access and/or cannot use `protected`, then really the only option you have short of using `public` is to stick everything into the same package.

This is because in Java, "subpackages" don't really exist -- for example, `java.util` is an entirely different package than `java.util.concurrent`; thus, whether `java.util.concurrent` is called that or `java.concurrent` doesn't make a difference from the standpoint of access scope. In either case, classes in `java.util.concurrent` won't be able to access package-private members from `java.util`. The naming is only for convenience, and doesn't indicate any actual hierarchy.

Thus, no matter how you name your packages, you won't be able to access package-private members from another package.

Comment: that cleared things up, thank you. I'll accept your answer if other better answers don't come along soon.

Comment: I have changed the answer as I found Honza Zidek's solution to have solved my problem. Thanks to you too :)

Comment: Huh, I've never heard of that concept before. Interesting solution!

Answer (score 0):

Have the system and dbengine classes extend the necessary classes in context and set fields/methods that the system and dbengine classes need to protected.

Comment: I need to use the objects from those classes, so extending classes would not help