# Eclipse says I need to import a class, when I already imported it's whole package

Tags: java, eclipse, import

In a class, I have this line:

```
import javax.swing.*;
```

However on the `StyledDocument doc = new DefaultStyledDocument();` Eclipse gives me an error (red line under the text) and offers to `import StyledDocument (javax.swing.text)`

Weird. I imported the entire `swing` package, why do I also need to import the class specifically?

Comment: Try to avoid `*` (star) form of imports.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the class is not in the `javax.swing` package, but in the `javax.swing.text` package. Imports are not recursive.

Comment: Really? Weird. Why not?

Comment: Because [subpackages in Java aren't really subpackages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23521857/design-of-java-classes-and-packages/23522042#23522042)

Comment: Because the Java designers decided so. And it makes sense. Most of the time, the classes you mainly use are at the top-level of a package tree (in javax.swing, for example), and the other packages mainly contain classes that are used internally by the root package. If there were recursive, importing org.hibernate.*, for example, would import hundreds of useless classes, that would clutter the namespace and potentially cause conflicts with other classes. Star imports are generally considered bad practice anyway. Use Ctrl-Shift-O, and Eclipse will import just what you need.