# Define `package private` access modifier in Java class

Tags: java

I want to Define `package private` *access modifier* in Java but the compiler doesn't agree like this:

```
    package private Name;
```

How do I need to do this?
thank you!

Comment: what does you mean?  What are you trying to acheive?

Comment: package don't have access modifier.

Comment: do you mean making the package private or making something "package private" ?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416074/isnt-package-private-member-access-synonymous-with-the-default-no-modifier

Answer (score 28):

"Package private" or "default" visibility modifier in Java is achieved by leaving out the visibility modifier (not the type). i.e.

```
String name;            // package private or default
public String name;
private String name;
protected String name;
```

Comment: An improvement in the answer: Therefore, you do not need to explicitly declare any variable as package-private, no exception. If you do not need anything, then you do not have it (Except for some wordy things.) because we want to achieve simplicity as much as possible.

Answer (score 4):

**There is no way you can define a package with an access level modifiers.Packages are named groups of related classes.**

You are confusing the the term **package private**. If you go over to the **java docs** you will see that **package private word is used to signify default or no modifier .It means that a class or any member without any modifier will be visible only within its own package.**

You can take reference from java [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html).